# jQuery UI Datepicker not working as advertised

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I got the jQuery UI tutorial for the datepicker [jquery tutorial](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) and put it into this  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/gq6En/107/)here. If, in the fiddle, you drag the orange box into the white box, the datepicker form appears, but if you focus on the form with the mouse, the calendar doesn't show --in the jQuery tutorial, the calendar shows if you focus on the form.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Make sure you setup the datepicker via... $(".datepicker").datepicker();

Comment: What about any CSS file inclusion? Don't you require to add that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not calling `.datepicker()` on your input. When you focus on the input field, there's nothing to do. You need to add `$("#datepicker").datepicker();`.

Here's an updated version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/PTtzv/.

Comment: thanks, check out the difference between your calendar and mine in my updated fiddle. Why is that? Have you set something differently that I can't see?  http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/gq6En/118/

Comment: @Michael - Yes, I've added the jQuery UI base CSS under "Add Resources". The link, in case you want is, is [http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css).

Comment: o. i see, there's a css file included. Thanks